# How to create global variables in azure function with python

Tags: python, azure-functions

**Python:** 3.7

**Cloud platform:** Azure

**Resource:** Azure function

**Goal:** Improve the speed of the function by using global variables

Hi everyone,

I developed an azure function with python. I found the following definition in order to use global variables:

```
CACHED_DATA = None


def main(req):
    global CACHED_DATA
    if CACHED_DATA is None:
        CACHED_DATA = load_json()

    # ... use CACHED_DATA in code
```

Source: [Python reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Cazurecli-linux%2Capplication-level)

I did not understand well what should add in my code. For that reason, I have the following questions:

1. Should the name of the variable always be named as "CACHE_DATA"?
2. If I set CACHED_DATA= None in my code, my understanding is every time that I call the function, this variable will be reset?.
3. Part of my current code is as following. Am I implementing correct that definition? If not, could someone tell how should I do it?

   ```
    stop_words = None
    vocabulary = None
    vectorizer_parameters = None

    def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:


    global stop_words
    global vocabulary
    global vectorizer_parameters


   if stop_words is None:

      stop_words_file_path = os_path.join(ROOT_DIR,'azure_function_app_sortierer','parameters','CustomStopWords.csv')
      df_stop_words = read_csv(stop_words_file_path)
      stop_words =df_stop_words['Stopwords'].tolist()

   if vocabulary is None or vectorizer_parameters is None:

      vocabulary = {}
      vectorizer_parameters = {}
      for v in ['clean_noCompound-tfidf_stopWords_unigrams', 'clean_noCompound-tfidf_stopWords_bigrams']:
         vocabulary_file_path = os_path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'azure_function_app_sortierer', 'model' , '00_' + v + '_Vocabulary.pkl')
         vocabulary[v] = joblib.load(vocabulary_file_path)
         vectorizer_parameters[v] = cfp.set_vectorizer_parameters(vectorizer_name=v,stopWords=stop_words,vocabulary=vocabulary[v])
   ```